# Can i init an Angular2 hybrid app without SystemJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular, systemjs, es6-module-loader, angular2-upgrade

I have a pretty big Angular 1 application.
I want to progressively migrate it into Angular 2 so i'm following the the [Official Upgrade Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html).

Now for some reason i'm getting one problem after the other with SystemJS but i also doubt that the old app will work with async module loading so i'd like to go on with the upgrade without using SystemJS or maybe using a much simpler module loader.

I tried go get rid of SystemJS but all the ng2 modules are wrapped in `System.register` calls.

So how can i setup a project that uses ng1 + ng2 and `UpgradeAdapter` without SystemJS?

EDIT:
I Get SystemJS is providing a polyfill for ES6 `import`. Let's say i can do without it because i'm only interested in running the application on ES6 compliant browsers.

Comment: Downvote without comment, very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Use full to me. I am in a situation where I need to load all the js files once as the application I am writing cannot have dynamic loading. why its down voted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular-all.umd.js and wrap your own modules in a [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) envelope.  That way you can load them dynamically or statically.